# Permission denied every installing/ removing pack

Tags: package-management, manpage

**UPDATE:**

I fixed it OK by removing/deleting the "/var/cache/man" folder
Then all things is OK now.
(The system will recreate the "/var/cache/man" folder automatically.

---

Every time I install or remove a pack, in terminal windows show errors as below:

[image]

What is problem, and how can I fix it.

I install packs by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install packname
```

The packs were installed on OS and run normally, Until now, I have not found abnormal yet when I launch the installed packs.
But, the errors as above are always showed every time I install new packs.

This is the terminal situation

```
sudo apt install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libbasicusageenvironment1 libcddb2 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdvbpsi10
  libebml4v5 libfaad2 libgroupsock8 libiso9660-8 libkate1 liblivemedia58
  libmad0 libmatroska6v5 libmpcdec6 libopenmpt-modplug1 libproxy-tools
  libqt5x11extras5 libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian
  libsidplay2 libsndio6.1 libssh2-1 libupnp6 libusageenvironment3 libvcdinfo0
  libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore8 vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2
  vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
Suggested packages:
  sndiod libdvdcss2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbasicusageenvironment1 libcddb2 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdvbpsi10
  libebml4v5 libfaad2 libgroupsock8 libiso9660-8 libkate1 liblivemedia58
  libmad0 libmatroska6v5 libmpcdec6 libopenmpt-modplug1 libproxy-tools
  libqt5x11extras5 libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian
  libsidplay2 libsndio6.1 libssh2-1 libupnp6 libusageenvironment3 libvcdinfo0
  libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore8 vlc vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2
  vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
0 upgraded, 41 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 81.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libmad0 amd64 0.15.1b-8ubuntu1 [71.5 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libmpcdec6 amd64 2:0.1~r459-4.1build1 [32.0 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libbasicusageenvironment1 amd64 2017.07.18-1 [15.8 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libcddb2 amd64 1.3.2-5fakesync1 [33.9 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libdvbpsi10 amd64 1.3.1-2 [47.4 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libebml4v5 amd64 1.3.4-2 [45.2 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libfaad2 amd64 2.8.1-2 [157 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libgroupsock8 amd64 2017.07.18-1 [21.2 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libiso9660-8 amd64 0.83-4.2ubuntu1 [18.4 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libkate1 amd64 0.4.1-7build1 [38.1 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 liblivemedia58 amd64 2017.07.18-1 [297 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libmatroska6v5 amd64 1.4.7-2 [120 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libopenmpt-modplug1 amd64 0.2.8760~beta27-1 [19.4 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libproxy-tools amd64 0.4.14-3 [5,192 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libqt5x11extras5 amd64 5.9.1-2 [8,820 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libresid-builder0c2a amd64 2.1.1-15ubuntu1 [31.3 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 libsdl1.2debian amd64 1.2.15+dfsg2-0.1 [174 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libsdl-image1.2 amd64 1.2.12-6 [29.0 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libsidplay2 amd64 2.1.1-15ubuntu1 [87.8 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libsndio6.1 amd64 1.1.0-3 [23.4 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libssh2-1 amd64 1.8.0-1 [73.2 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libusageenvironment3 amd64 2017.07.18-1 [6,786 B]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libvcdinfo0 amd64 0.7.24+dfsg-0.2 [90.7 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libvlccore8 amd64 2.2.6-6 [412 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libvlc5 amd64 2.2.6-6 [70.5 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libvlc-bin amd64 2.2.6-6 [27.1 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-bin amd64 2.2.6-6 [63.2 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libdc1394-22 amd64 2.2.5-1 [77.5 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libdca0 amd64 0.0.5-10 [100.0 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libupnp6 amd64 1:1.6.22-1 [121 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-data all 2.2.6-6 [340 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-plugin-base amd64 2.2.6-6 [7,823 kB]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-plugin-qt amd64 2.2.6-6 [991 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-plugin-video-output amd64 2.2.6-6 [54.0 kB]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-l10n all 2.2.6-6 [5,475 kB]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc amd64 2.2.6-6 [40.6 kB]
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-plugin-notify amd64 2.2.6-6 [6,140 B]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-plugin-samba amd64 2.2.6-6 [5,772 B]
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-plugin-skins2 amd64 2.2.6-6 [458 kB]
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-plugin-video-splitter amd64 2.2.6-6 [18.7 kB]
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 vlc-plugin-visualization amd64 2.2.6-6 [27.4 kB]
Fetched 17.6 MB in 9s (1,779 kB/s)                                             
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package libmad0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 183886 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libmad0_0.15.1b-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmad0:amd64 (0.15.1b-8ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmpcdec6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libmpcdec6_2%3a0.1~r459-4.1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpcdec6:amd64 (2:0.1~r459-4.1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbasicusageenvironment1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libbasicusageenvironment1_2017.07.18-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbasicusageenvironment1:amd64 (2017.07.18-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcddb2.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libcddb2_1.3.2-5fakesync1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcddb2 (1.3.2-5fakesync1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdvbpsi10:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libdvbpsi10_1.3.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdvbpsi10:amd64 (1.3.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libebml4v5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libebml4v5_1.3.4-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libebml4v5:amd64 (1.3.4-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfaad2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libfaad2_2.8.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfaad2:amd64 (2.8.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgroupsock8:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libgroupsock8_2017.07.18-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgroupsock8:amd64 (2017.07.18-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libiso9660-8:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libiso9660-8_0.83-4.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libiso9660-8:amd64 (0.83-4.2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkate1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libkate1_0.4.1-7build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkate1:amd64 (0.4.1-7build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblivemedia58:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-liblivemedia58_2017.07.18-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblivemedia58:amd64 (2017.07.18-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmatroska6v5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libmatroska6v5_1.4.7-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmatroska6v5:amd64 (1.4.7-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libopenmpt-modplug1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libopenmpt-modplug1_0.2.8760~beta27-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopenmpt-modplug1:amd64 (0.2.8760~beta27-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libproxy-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libproxy-tools_0.4.14-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libproxy-tools (0.4.14-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5x11extras5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libqt5x11extras5_5.9.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5x11extras5:amd64 (5.9.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libresid-builder0c2a.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libresid-builder0c2a_2.1.1-15ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libresid-builder0c2a (2.1.1-15ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsdl1.2debian:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libsdl1.2debian_1.2.15+dfsg2-0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15+dfsg2-0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsdl-image1.2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libsdl-image1.2_1.2.12-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsdl-image1.2:amd64 (1.2.12-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsidplay2.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libsidplay2_2.1.1-15ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsidplay2 (2.1.1-15ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsndio6.1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../19-libsndio6.1_1.1.0-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsndio6.1:amd64 (1.1.0-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssh2-1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../20-libssh2-1_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssh2-1:amd64 (1.8.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libusageenvironment3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../21-libusageenvironment3_2017.07.18-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libusageenvironment3:amd64 (2017.07.18-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvcdinfo0.
Preparing to unpack .../22-libvcdinfo0_0.7.24+dfsg-0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvcdinfo0 (0.7.24+dfsg-0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvlccore8:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../23-libvlccore8_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvlccore8:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvlc5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../24-libvlc5_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvlc5:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvlc-bin:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../25-libvlc-bin_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvlc-bin:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../26-vlc-bin_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-bin (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdc1394-22:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../27-libdc1394-22_2.2.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdc1394-22:amd64 (2.2.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdca0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../28-libdca0_0.0.5-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdca0:amd64 (0.0.5-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libupnp6.
Preparing to unpack .../29-libupnp6_1%3a1.6.22-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libupnp6 (1:1.6.22-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-data.
Preparing to unpack .../30-vlc-data_2.2.6-6_all.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-data (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-plugin-base:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../31-vlc-plugin-base_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-plugin-base:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-plugin-qt:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../32-vlc-plugin-qt_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-plugin-qt:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-plugin-video-output:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../33-vlc-plugin-video-output_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-plugin-video-output:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-l10n.
Preparing to unpack .../34-vlc-l10n_2.2.6-6_all.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-l10n (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc.
Preparing to unpack .../35-vlc_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-plugin-notify:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../36-vlc-plugin-notify_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-plugin-notify:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-plugin-samba:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../37-vlc-plugin-samba_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-plugin-samba:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-plugin-skins2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../38-vlc-plugin-skins2_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-plugin-skins2:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-plugin-video-splitter:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../39-vlc-plugin-video-splitter_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-plugin-video-splitter:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-plugin-visualization:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../40-vlc-plugin-visualization_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-plugin-visualization:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up libusageenvironment3:amd64 (2017.07.18-1) ...
Setting up libqt5x11extras5:amd64 (5.9.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up vlc-data (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up libdvbpsi10:amd64 (1.3.1-2) ...
Setting up libmpcdec6:amd64 (2:0.1~r459-4.1build1) ...
Setting up libbasicusageenvironment1:amd64 (2017.07.18-1) ...
Setting up libproxy-tools (0.4.14-3) ...
Setting up libiso9660-8:amd64 (0.83-4.2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libebml4v5:amd64 (1.3.4-2) ...
Setting up libvlccore8:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up libfaad2:amd64 (2.8.1-2) ...
Setting up libkate1:amd64 (0.4.1-7build1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-qt:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15+dfsg2-0.1) ...
Setting up libdc1394-22:amd64 (2.2.5-1) ...
Setting up liblivemedia58:amd64 (2017.07.18-1) ...
Setting up vlc-l10n (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-video-output:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up libssh2-1:amd64 (1.8.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libupnp6 (1:1.6.22-1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-video-splitter:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up libcddb2 (1.3.2-5fakesync1) ...
Setting up libgroupsock8:amd64 (2017.07.18-1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-skins2:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/da/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/da/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/da/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/fa/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/id/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/id/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/id/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/pl/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/pl/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/pl/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/is/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/lv/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/ar/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/it/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/it/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/it/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/es/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/es/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/es/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/zh_CN/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/zh_CN/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/zh_CN/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/bg/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/de/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/de/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/de/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/pt_BR/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/pt_BR/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/pt_BR/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/sv/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/sv/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/sv/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/hu/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/hu/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/hu/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/ms/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/fr.ISO8859-1/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/fr.ISO8859-1/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/fr.ISO8859-1/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/gl/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/he/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/hr/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/ko/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/ko/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/ko/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/fr.UTF-8/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/fr.UTF-8/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/fr.UTF-8/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/sl/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/sl/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/sl/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/ro/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/ru/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/ru/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/ru/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/nl/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/nl/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/nl/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/sr/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/zh_TW/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/zh_TW/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/zh_TW/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/ja/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/ja/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/ja/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/pt/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/pt/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/pt/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/eu/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/tr/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/tr/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/tr/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/el/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/sk/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/ca/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/lt/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/fi/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/fi/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/fi/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/vi/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/cs/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/cs/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/cs/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/fr/CACHEDIR.TAG: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/mandb: can't remove /var/cache/man/fr/CACHEDIR.TAG: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/fr/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/nb/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/et/4065: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: fopen /var/cache/man/uk/4065: Permission denied
Setting up vlc-plugin-visualization:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libsdl-image1.2:amd64 (1.2.12-6) ...
Setting up libmad0:amd64 (0.15.1b-8ubuntu1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-notify:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up libresid-builder0c2a (2.1.1-15ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsidplay2 (2.1.1-15ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdca0:amd64 (0.0.5-10) ...
Setting up libsndio6.1:amd64 (1.1.0-3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
Setting up libopenmpt-modplug1:amd64 (0.2.8760~beta27-1) ...
Setting up libvcdinfo0 (0.7.24+dfsg-0.2) ...
Setting up libmatroska6v5:amd64 (1.4.7-2) ...
Setting up libvlc5:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-samba:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up libvlc-bin:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-base:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up vlc-bin (2.2.6-6) ...
Setting up vlc (2.2.6-6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for libvlc-bin:amd64 (2.2.6-6) ...
```

@dedunumax:
This is the output of ls -lha /var/cache/man/

```
ls -lha /var/cache/man/
total 1.1M
drwxr-xr-x 53 man  man  4.0K Mar 23 10:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 ar
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 bg
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 ca
-rw-r--r--  1 man  man   190 Mar 19 13:28 CACHEDIR.TAG
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 01:37 cat1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 01:37 cat2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 01:37 cat3
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 01:37 cat4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 01:37 cat5
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 01:37 cat6
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 01:37 cat7
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 01:37 cat8
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 cs
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 da
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 de
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 el
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 es
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 et
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 eu
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 fa
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 fi
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 fr
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 fr.ISO8859-1
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 fr.UTF-8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 gl
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 he
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 hr
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 hu
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 id
-rw-r--r--  1 man  man  857K Mar 23 10:48 index.db
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 is
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 it
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 ja
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 ko
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 lt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 lv
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 ms
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 nb
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 nl
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 pl
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 pt
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 pt_BR
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 ro
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 ru
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 sk
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 sl
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 sr
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 sv
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 tr
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 uk
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 17 22:07 vi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 zh_CN
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 18 21:09 zh_TW
```

@muru:
This is the output of namei -lx /var/cache/man/da/CACHEDIR.TAG

```
    namei -lx /var/cache/man/da/CACHEDIR.TAG
f: /var/cache/man/da/CACHEDIR.TAG
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
Drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxr-xr-x root root cache
drwxr-xr-x man  man  man
drwxr-xr-x root root da
-rw-r--r-- root root CACHEDIR.TAG
```

This is the output of df /var/cache/man/da/

```
df /var/cache/man/da/
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       59340932 9911984  46384804  18% /var
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the text from terminal windows, rather than posting a screen shot!  Can you append your question to include the command that you used to create the display above?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -lha /var/cache/man/`

Comment: Add the output of `namei -lx  /var/cache/man/da/CACHEDIR.TAG` and `df /var/cache/man/da/`, please.

Comment: Your permissions are messed up. This is how it looks on my system:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4KT97BdPzS/ - all directories owned by `man:root` and setgid. Did you recursively `chown` `/var`?

Comment: I don't know why, I only have a action is I moved then mounting /var folder to other partition.
so, how do i fix it now please.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set owner of directory `/var/cache/man/` to usr man. This is the command:

```
chown -R man: /var/cache/man/
```

and for security set the permission 755 (owner RWX, group RX, other RX) to all directories:

```
chmod -R 755 /var/cache/man/
```